# Documentation Template for SSAS Cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, cube

I need a template to document an SSAS cube.

Cube info

- Single source of data
- One main Fact table
- Five direct dimensions
- Two many-to-many dimensions
- 48 Partitions, 48 Aggregations

Can anyone point me to design templates for SSAS cubes?

Answer (score 2):

Re: document; I have **[this one](http://www.u2u.be/res/SQL05_ASDoc.aspx)** bookmarked for a while now, though did not try it myself. If you use it, do comment.
 Also **[see here](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-tools)** and filter by "document".

Comment: I did use the utility to document the structure. It did a fairly decent job of marking down the structure. It did not get me the diagrams that are a part of my cube, and I think it would have been pretty cool if they could do that.

Comment: The above link does not work any more. Try this instead: http://www.u2u.be/Software

Answer (score 1):

For a price you can have all in all using [BI Documenter](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-Documenter).